# Cucumber cannot be resolved to a type. @RunWith(Cucumber.class)

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I am trying to execute as a maven project, I have added the dependencies in pom file and in maven dependencies also I can find the cucumber-junit jars. But still I cannot import the appropriate jar. Getting `" The import cucumber.api.junit cannot be resolved "`. Please find the attached screenshot

Dependency added in maven is

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.5</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

[image]

Folder structure of TestRunner Class

[image]

Comment: please provide your dependency inside your pom file

Comment: without providing dependency inside pom file how will jars get downloaded at maven dependencies. I added it in pom file

Comment: please edit the question and send the dependency you have added because the scope of dependency is important !

Comment: sorry I have added the dependencies what I used in my Pom file. Please help me solve this one

Comment: what is the folder structure ? what have you put under src folder ? where is the class TestRunner located in your application ?

Comment: @Mehdi: i have added screenshot, Please find it for folder structure

Comment: check the answer !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options

**1- change your folder structure:**

```
src
  |
  test
     |
     your-package
                |
                YourClass
```

**2- You can remove the scope test from the dependency as follows:**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.5</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi  . your answer helped me alot

Comment: @Deepak_Mahalingam yrw :)

Comment: pin point solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You need these imports:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
```